# How to grab particular String in Json String in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

My json String is

```
{
"id":"boi12343",
"prompt":
        "{\"sch\":[
                          [\"type\",\"field_name\",\"label\",\"tool_tip\",\"required\",\"default_value\"],
                          [\"Textfield\",\"batch_number\",\"Batch Number\",\"Yea, batch number\",\"Y\",\"123\"],
                          [\"DateField\",\"start_date\",\"Start Date\",\"Start Date\",\"\",\"05\/05\/2014\"]
                  ]
         }",

"contact_info":[
                  ["name","email","phone"],
                  ["John","jdo@gmail.com","555555555"]
               ]

}
```

I can grab id in AngularJS using data.id and data.contact_info[1][0] gives me "John" but how to grab

"Textfield"? I tried data.promt.sch[1][0] but it dosant work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.prompt.sch[1][0]` doesn't work because the quote marks around the value of the `prompt` property are backslash escaped. So `data.prompt` evaluates to a string that contains a JSON data structure.

Try something like this:

```
JSON.parse(data.prompt).sch[1][0]
```